# Map customer attribute to account/contact attribute in a workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Statement: In plain CRM 2015 installation its possible to map customer attribute in campaign response to account/contact in opportunity, but not if its a CRM 2013 installation upgraded to CRM 2015.

True or false? :-)

Best regards Knut Myre

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGay6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False.  The fact that you upgraded from 2013 has no bearing on the workflow editor's UI or capabilities